# Subjonctif et antériorité par rapport au passé composé

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, subjonctif

Comment exprimer l'antériorité par rapport au passé composé en employant le subjonctif ? Est-ce qu'on emploie le subjonctif passé, le subjonctif plus-que-parfait ou quelquechose d'autre ?
Par exemple

> J'ai oublié de faire mon devoir bien que ma mère m'en (rappeler) plusieurs fois.

Ait rappelé/eût rappelé ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le pronom ***en*** est curieux. S'il faut le conserver, on pourra écrire :

> J'ai oublié de faire mon devoir bien que ma mère **m'en ait rappelé** plusieurs fois la nécessité.

Sinon :

> J'ai oublié de faire mon devoir bien que ma mère **me l'ait rappelé** plusieurs fois.

Le présent du subjonctif (que l'on ne peut pas distinguer du présent de l'indicatif ici) n'est pas vraiment utilisable, la chronologie n'étant pas respectée.

> J'ai oublié de faire mon devoir bien que ma mère <s>me le rappelle</s> plusieurs fois.

Le présent est toutefois possible s'il s'agit d'une répétition:

> J'ai oublié de faire mon devoir bien que ma mère **me le rappelle** plusieurs fois par jour.

Un français formel ou littéraire peut employer le subjonctif plus-que-parfait mais la principale sera alors au plus-que-parfait de l'indicatif :

> **J'avais oublié** de faire mon devoir bien que ma mère **me l'eût rappelé** plusieurs fois.

Comment: Très clair. On pourrait ajouter que le subjonctif plus-que-parfait ne convient pas, pas seulement parce qu'il est désuet, mais aussi parce qu'on veut ici simplement exprimer un passé par rapport à une situation présente, "je constate maintenant que mon devoir n'est pas fait"

Comment: Je ne comprends pas cette partie : *Un français formel ou littéraire peut employer le subjonctif plus-que-parfait mais la principale doit alors être au passé*. Mais la principale est déjà au passé composé, non ?

Comment: @Damien Si on voulait employer l'indicatif dans cette phrase, est-ce qu'on dirait : *J'ai oublié de faire mon devoir même si ma mère me l'a rappelé plusieurs fois* ou *J'ai oublié de faire mon devoir même si ma mère me l'avait rappelé plusieurs fois.* ?

Comment: @lmc C'est vrai. Je corrige. Ce que je voulais dire, c'est que le passé composé conduit ici à une situation qui s'achève dans le présent, contrairement à l'imparfait où elle est s'achève dans le passé.

Comment: @lmc Je préfère la première version, plus simple et qui me semble plus logique. Elle suit la même règle que la version *bien que + subjonctif*.

Comment: @Damien Désolée de vous ennuyer, mais je vois maintenant que mon exemple n'est pas bon. Prenons cet exemple : *Même si j'avais vu Pierre plusieurs fois, je ne l'ai pas reconnu hier dans la rue.* Cela devient : *Bien que j'aie vu Pierre plusieurs fois, je ne l'ai pas reconnu hier dans la rue* n'est-ce pas ? Donc, le plus-que-parfait dans l'indicatif n'implique pas qu'on va employer le plus-que-parfait dans le subjonctif..?

Comment: @lmc Un point important est que dans *je ne l'ai pas reconnu hier dans la rue*, l'action s'est terminée dans le passé. On utilisait autrefois le passé simple (*je ne le reconnus pas*) dans ce cas. Le passé simple n'est plus très utilisé. Le fait d'utiliser le passé composé (ou le plus-que-parfait) dans différentes circonstances implique qu'il faut plutôt considérer le moment où l'action s'est terminée. Vous ne m'ennuyez pas, mais ça me gêne de monopoliser le post de jlliagre. Vous devriez vous adresser à lui, il saura vous répondre !

Answer (score -4):

Tout d'abord il faut voir qu'il existe une incertitude sur l'antécédent de « en » ; s'agit il de « faire mon devoir »  ou bien s'agit-il de « oublier de faire mon devoir » ; bien que la précision « plusieurs fois » tende à montrer qu'il ne s'agit pas de rappeler l'oubli mais de rappeler le devoir non fait, il n'existe pas une forte connexion et il vaut mieux changer la phrase selon moi pour que toutes les connexions soient bien marquées.
Le remplacement du pronom ne change rien d'autre à la phrase et le résultat ci-dessous montre que le subjonctif passé est le temps utilisé.

J'ai oublié de faire mon devoir bien que ma mère m'ait rappelé plusieurs fois ce travail. (*« ce travail » évite la répétition, mais on peut aussi dire « de le faire »*)

Si l'on se réfère à la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4238) il faut utiliser le subjonctif (généralement le subjonctif avec « bien que »). De nombreuses sources, comme [celle-ci](https://forum.lefigaro.fr/forum/affich-190-que-je-suis-ou-que-je-sois), 
indiquent que le subjonctif est nécessaire.

Le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bien) donne les précisions suivantes ;

> [**S'emploie avec un verbe gén. au subj., except. à l'ind. ou au cond. dans la lang. fam.**, littér.; s'emploie aussi avec un part. prés. ou un adj. p. ell. du verbe; marque la concession]

Donc, je pense qu'en parlant on ne donnera toujours pas l'impression de quelqu'un qui parle mal si on utilise le subjonctif parce que le monde éduqué l'emploie toujours. On pourra aussi utiliser le passé composé ; il est utile de savoir que certaines personnes concernées de près par la langue française, en particulier de telles personnes s'exprimant sur le présent site (aCOSwt, jlliagre, par exemple) découragent l'utilisation du subjonctif dans le présent cas et recommandent l'utilisation seule de l'indicatif (courant de pensée contemporain); leur argumentation, bien que apparemment  non formulée très formellement, serait que la réalisation de l'action ne fait aucun doute, ce dont on ne peut pas douter, dans la phrase proposée.

*Justification du passé du subjonctif ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1175))*

> Si l’action exprimée par le verbe de la subordonnée s’est passée avant celle de la principale, le verbe de la subordonnée est en principe au plus-que-parfait du subjonctif, afin de marquer cette antériorité. Dans ce cas, il est toutefois admis d’employer le présent du subjonctif ou le passé du subjonctif.

« m'eût rappelé », le plus-que-parfait, ne se trouve que dans la langue littéraire et son utilisation dans la correspondance courante parait plutôt affectée.

Comment: Le « monde éduqué », dont apparemment, ni moi, ni @aCOSwt ne faisons partie n'a pas besoin de porte-parole et évite d'écrire des expressions aussi peu idiomatiques que certaines des tiennes... (*en particulier de telles personnes s'exprimant sur le présent site*) Quand vas-tu enfin reconnaître que le français n'est pas ta langue maternelle ? (ni l'anglais semble-t-il).

Comment: @jlliagre 1/ ll n'y a aucune insinuation. 2/ Secondement il est bien prétentieux de votre part de me supposer votre porte parole. 3/ Je donne comme référence qui il me plait. 4/ Ce que j'avance est exact, il n'y a qu'à vérifier vos écrits. 5/ Vous auriez  d'intelligence pour deux sous vous vous estimeriez heureux que votre point de vue ne soit  pas négligé.

Comment: 1/ Il suffit de savoir lire pour comprendre que tu te paies notre tête (« le monde éduqué emploie toujours le subjonctif » mais « aCOSw et jlliagre recommandent le présent »). 2/ alors évite de me citer (surtout pour dire des conneries). 3/ Tu ne donnes aucune référence. 4/ Peut-être, mais met alors des liens vers les réponses où c'est affirmé. 5/ Arrête de me vouvoyer, ça casse l'ambiance.

Comment: @jlliagre Le monde éduqué n'est pas le monde qui se soucie des pourquois et des comments du langage, c'est le monde qui a été formé à bien le parler et qui l'utilise machinalement, justement pour cette raison. Il n'est pas le monde que le langage concerne de près, même si ce dernier en fait partie et doit forcément être éduqué pour se permettre de donner des avis. Je vous ai déjà fait part du fait que je ne tutoie personne, en particulier personne que je sois loin de connaitre intimement.

Comment: *J'ai oublié de faire mon devoir bien que ma mère m'ait rappelé plusieurs fois de ce travail.* -> En français on rappelle **quelque chose** à quelqu'un et non **de quelque chose**.

Comment: @Sharcoux C'est corrigé, merci.

Comment: Nommer explicitement des usagers de ce site de manière aussi peu valorisante est très inélégant. Il conviendrait de réviser. -1 en attendant.

Comment: @Montéedelait Non, il n'y a rien de dévalorisant, simplement un constat de fait; j'ai moi-même changé au moins une fois un subjonctif en un indicatif suite aux injonctions de user jlliagre qui considère que dans certains cas ce mode est excessif. Dans l'exemple « Je l'oublie bien que l'on me le dise souvent. » il trouve le subjonctif irraisonnable puisque l'action est faite; selon lui il faut dire « Je l'oublie bien qu'on me le dit souvent. » et je ne peux pas contredire cela, son idée semble correcte; seulement, toute ma vie j'ai lu et entendu (champ 1)

Comment: @Montéedelait  ce type de phrase avec le verbe en question au subjonctif (si pas toujours). La BDL, par exemple, dit qu'après « bien que » le subjonctif est toujours utilisé; il y a d'autres sources qui l'affirment. Il n'est pas le seul d'ailleurs et l'autre utilisateur que je cite, lequel est très informé sur la grammaire française sinon un spécialiste décrie assez souvent dans ses commentaires les gens qu'il appelle les obstinés du subjonctif (ou quelque chose comme ça, je ne peux pas passer des heures à faire de la recherche dans cette masse inaccessible d'écrits qu'est le FSE). (fin)

Comment: Je n'ai pas besoin de vos raisonnements. L'exemple que vous donnez *(je l'oublie bien qu'on me le dise souvent)* me semble aussi correct à moi, mais ce n'est pas là que le bât blesse. Les utilisateurs sont nommés, et mis en contraste avec le monde éduqué. Ça, c'est peu valorisant et inélégant. Je maintiens mon vote négatif.

Comment: @jlliagre Maintenez votre vote envers et par dessus tout, mais je ne vois aucune raison de ne pas faire part d'un courant d'esprit réel et de mentionner ceux qui en sont les responsables, comme de toute façon ils ne peuvent que se juger responsables de leurs dires et opinions, comme l'on se doit de nommer les sources autant que possible et comme il ne s'agit que d'opinions et en aucune façon d'accusations ou de crimes quelconques. Je n'ai rien à dissimuler.

Comment: Je n'avais pas "downvoté" mais puisque c'est expressément demandé, -1 !

Comment: @Fólkvangr Le pourquoi essentiellement est l'avis des personnes que je cite et qui, c'est mon opinion personnelle, reflète la pensée d'autres individus. Je dois dire que dans mon explication je ne cherche pas une justification logique mais seulement une évaluation du degré d'acceptabilité des normes actuelles; que le subjonctif soit logiquement justifié ou non, si tout le monde l'utilise, la personne divergeant de cette norme n'est pas avantagée et elle aurait intérêt à se conformer tant qu'un changement n'a pas été amorcé (bien qu'il ne soit/n'est refusé à personne d'être un pionnier).